# How can I store data from MySQL database into array indexed by id?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo

I store some data from the MySQL database into an array:

```
$p = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments;');
while ($row = $p->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
   $commentlist[$row['id']] = $row['text'];
}  


  foreach($commentlist as $key => $value) {
      echo $key;
      echo $value;
  }
```

Now I have access to the values `id` and `text`. But I also need to have access to the value `image` (which is another row in the MySQL database). But how can I store it if I have only two available elements: key and value?

Comment: it will be helpful if you can show sample structure of your table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need other fields, then you should store the whole row in $value.

However, PDO is a little more than everyone think. It can give you the desired result in a single call thanks to, [fetchAll() method with PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE modifier](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#unique):

```
$commentlist = $db->query('SELECT * FROM comments;')->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE);
```

Now you can foreach over comments

```
foreach($commentlist as $id => $value) {
    echo $id;
    echo $value['text'];
    echo $value['image'];
}
```